# How to get most recent values in SQL based on a condition

Tags: sql, join, row-number

I’ve been trying various things to get the data in a format I need but to no avail. I need to combine 3 tables that shows everything from 1 table and add in an additional column that shows the most RECENT value from table 2 but take into account a condition from table 3. Showing the tables will make more sense...
I’ve simplied the tables. So here’s the workorder table:

```
workorderid wonum   siteid
1000    5000    SITE1
1001    5001    SITE1
1002    5002    SITE1
1003    5003    SITE1
1004    5000    SITE2
1005    5001    SITE2
1006    5002    SITE2
1007    5004    SITE1
```

I need to use the wonum and siteid to get the pay_value – but there can be multiple payments for each work order. I need to get the most recent payment where the payment hasn’t been cancelled. Unfortunately that’s held in the purchase_req table. This is the payment_wos table

```
wonum_ref   siteid  pay_numref  pay_value
5000    SITE1   12345   1000.00
5001    SITE1   12345   1023.52
5002    SITE1   12346   52.32
5003    SITE1   12347   452.12
5000    SITE2   12348   154.21
5000    SITE1   12347   852.25
5001    SITE2   12350   953.86
5002    SITE2   12349   587.78
```

purchase_req table:

```
pay_num siteid  status  sent_date
12345   SITE1   CANCEL  2015-11-02 15:00
12346   SITE1   SENT    2015-11-03 13:00
12347   SITE1   SENT    2015-11-04 12:00
12348   SITE2   APPROVED    2015-11-04 15:00
12349   SITE2   CANCEL  2015-11-05 11:00
12350   SITE2   SENT    2015-11-06 15:00
```

So for the example data shown, I need to get the result below:

```
workorderid wonum   siteid  pay_value
1000    5000    SITE1   852.25
1001    5001    SITE1   NULL
1002    5002    SITE1   52.32
1003    5003    SITE1   452.12
1004    5000    SITE2   154.12
1005    5001    SITE2   953.86
1006    5002    SITE2   NULL
1007    5004    SITE1   NULL
```

So for example workorderid 1001 is showing the pay_value as NULL as the most recent payment is in a status of ‘CANCEL’.
Also for example workorderid 1007 is showing the pay_value as NULL as well as there is no payment for it.
With my attempt below it only shows work orders where there is a payment. If I tweak the where clause so that instead of
 pr.status not in ('CANCEL') 
it says 
(pr.status not in ('CANCEL') or pr.status is null) 
Then this shows all work orders except for the ones where EVERY payment is in a status of ‘CANCEL’. I need it to show every single work order :S.
Any help would be much appreciated. SQL is below:

```
;with
Pay_Per_WO
AS
(
select w.workorderid, w.wonum, p.wonumref, w.siteid as wsiteid, p.siteid as psiteid, p.pay_numref, p.pay_value, w.siteid, pr.sent_date, pr.status, pr.siteid as prsiteid, pr.pay_num
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY w.workorderid order by  MAX(pr.sent_date) Desc) payorder
from workorder w
left join payment_wos p
on w.wonum = p.wonumref and w.siteid = p.siteid
left join pr
on p.pay_numref = pr.pay_num and p.siteid = pr.siteid  
where
pr.status not in ('CANCEL')
group by w.workorderid, w.wonum, p.wonumref, w.siteid, p.siteid, p.pay_numref, p.pay_value, w.siteid, pr.sent_date, pr.status, pr.siteid, pr.pay_num
)

,
Pay_Calc
AS
(
Select 
a.workorderid, a.wonum, a.siteid, a.pay_value
from Pay_Per_WO a 
WHERE a.payorder = 1
group by a.workorderid, a.wonum, a.siteid, a.pay_value
)

select * from Pay_Calc
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test it as I dont have your tables, but should be something like this:

```
with q1 as
(select * from 
  (select
    pw.wonum_ref,
    pw.site_id,
    pw.pay_value,
    rank() over (partition by pw.pay_num,pw.site_id order by pr.sent_date desc) rnk
  from payment_wos pw
  left outer join purchase_req pr on pw.pay_num = pr.pay_num and pw.site_id = pr.site_id 
  where pr.status != 'CANCEL')
where rnk = 1)
select
  wo.workorderid,
  q1.wonum_ref,
  q1.site_id,
  q1.pay_value
from workorder wo
left outer join q1 ON wo.wonum = q1.wonum_ref AND wo.siteid = q1.site_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to this query is enumerating the non-cancelled "wos".  This is just a `join` along with `row_number()`:

```
select w.*,
       row_number() over (partition by wonum_ref, siteid order by r.sent_date desc) as seqnum
from payment_wos w join
     purchase_req r
     on w.pay_numref = r.pay_numref
where r.status <> 'CANCEL';
```

You can then join this to `work_order`:

```
select wo.workorderid, wo.wonum, wo.siteid, wr.pay_value
from work_order wo left join
     (select w.*,
             row_number() over (partition by wonum_ref, siteid order by r.sent_date desc) as seqnum
      from payment_wos w join
           purchase_req r
           on w.pay_numref = r.pay_numref
      where r.status <> 'CANCEL'
     ) wr
     on wo.wonum_ref = wr.wonum_ref and wo.siteid = wr.siteid and wr.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, although this still shows incorrect values in the case where every payment has been cancelled. In this scenario the pay_value is showing as the oldest cancelled value instead of null (or zero).

Comment: @Tantalus86 . . . It should be showing `NULL` in that case.  The `WHERE` clause is processed before the `row_number()`, so I don't see how a cancelled value could be included.  Is it possible that `'CANCEL'` could be subtly different in some records?